# Pass a template string to a Jinja macro

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to render a template string from a macro. I tried to do it with the following macro that renders the template using `{{ comment|safe }}`, but variables in the template such as `{{ name }}` are rendered literally instead of with the value of `name`. How can I allow variable data in a macro argument?

```html
{% macro comment_el(image_url, name, comment) %}
  <div class="media no-border-top">
    <div class="media-left">
      <a href="{{ outgoing_url }}" >
        <img class="media-object" src="{{ image_url }}" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ outgoing_url }}" >{{ name }}</a></h4>
      <p>{{ comment|safe }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

```html
{{ comment_el(
    url_for("static", filename="img/c01.jpg"),
    "Some Name",
    "This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that {{ name }} is an amazing person"
) }}
```

Output:

```
<p>This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that {{ name }} is an amazing person</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried this as the third parameter to comment_el? "This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that " + name + " is an amazing person"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's not possible.

However, you can have a `caller` in Jinja macros that lets you pass a block:

```
{% macro comment_el(image_url, name) %}
    ...
    <div class="media-body">
      <p>{{ caller() }}</p>
    </div>
    ...
{% endmacro %}
```

Then call it like this:

```
{% call comment_el(url_for("static", filename="img/c01.jpg"), "Some Name") -%}
    This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that {{ name }} is an amazing person 
{%- endcall %}
```

Relevant docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#call

---

Another option to solve it would be this:

```
{% set comment -%}
    This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that {{ name }} is an amazing person
{%- endset %}
{{ comment_el(url_for("static", filename="img/c01.jpg"),
    "Some Name",
    comment
) }}
```

Relevant docs: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#block-assignments

---

For the sake of completeness, you could also use formatting:

```
{{ comment_el(url_for("static", filename="img/c01.jpg"),
"Some Name",
"This comment is amazing. All I want to say is that %s is an amazing person" | format(name)
) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a high quality answer. Your contribution is what makes S.O. a great community